# How to check/redirect in every method of any controller in ASP NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm looking for a way to do this in every Method of every Controller, even for those that doesn't return an IActionResult (I'll talking about this forward):

1. Get User.Claim to get the user info logged into the site.
2. Check if the user is blocked in the database (I've my own repositories working already)
3. Redirect a user to a Page that shows "you are blocked" like the workflow of Exceptions does.

## **Considerations and tries that I already made:**

- Can't get this from a Claim in order to work it with ViewStart because I need the block works in the same moment the database were updated. The Claim should the user sign out and sign in.
- Can't do this trough a controller that returns a boolean with Json in
  every page because the user could stop the redirect
- I've several methods that returns partialviews, objects, lists, anything but IActionResult. I don't care if that doesn't work for two reasons:

  - It should be triggered by the main view that calls those through ajax.
  - The user is blocked anyway so I don't care if it see the page broken.
- My security workflow is like this:

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  [Authorize(Policy = "Users")]
  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "MyAppScheme")]

  public IActionResult GetRep() {
       //Do things
  }
  ```

Right now I'm trying do a middleware but I'm new in NET Core at so deep level, so can't compile neither. Also working trying to call my userRepository from the ViewStart

Comment: Why don't you use middlewares which will work globally in your application. Action filter would be the best choice [Chekc MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @RabbyHasan thanks! Yes is what im trying but dont know how do it correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is using a middleware. Here you have an example:

```
internal class UserMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

    public UserMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        this.userRepository = userRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepository));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        Claim clientId = httpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        bool isBlocked = await this.userRepository.CheckUser(clientId);

        if (isBlocked)
        {
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("You are blocked.");
            return;
        }

        await this.next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Then in your startup method you should call it before mapping your controllers:

```
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Other stuff...

    app.UseMiddleware<UserMiddleware>();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: Now I've several issues with 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.'

Comment: Dont know why because Im doing Usuarios user = await _context.Users.Where(u => u.Guid == guid && u.Deleted == 0 && u.Blocked == 0).FirstAsync();